# HSTORE order by key/value where the value is a string representation of an integer

Tags: postgresql, hstore

I'm working with an existing database and have an hstore column with the contents being a key pointing to an integer stored as a string.

I'm working with code that attempts to sort by that value but unfortunately, since it's a string, I get the unsurprising behavior that "10" comes before "2".  I do not have license to change the data in the table, so I'm looking for a way to write the order so that it orders by the value as an integer rather than as the string it naturally is.

Here is some toy SQL to hopefully better show what I'm asking:

```
INSERT INTO hstore_test (sale) 
        VALUES ('"milk"=>"4", 
                 "bread"=>"2", 
                 "bananas"=>"12", 
                 "cereal"=>"1"');
```

Now at this point I want to get all the things, sorted by milk -> value:

```
SELECT * FROM hstore_test ORDER BY sale -> 'milk';
```

This unfortunately sorts by the string value of milk ("4" in the example above).

I've been kind of envisioning something like

```
SELECT * FROM hstore_test ORDER BY CAST(sale -> 'milk' as INT);
```

but I can't convince myself that's correct.

Comment: Have you tried it? Did it give you an error?

Comment: uh, yeah, it did. I had a syntax error in my code. Fixed that, entire thing works now. Do I delete this or leave it up as a cautionary tale?

Comment: You could answer it yourself. hstore is explicitly string-to-string so a cast is the right way to go.